# Using x:anyType instead of xsi:type gives Jaxb marshalling errors

Tags: xsd, jaxb, any

I want to avoid xsi:type in an element and add the child elements at runtime based on some condition

I have option element defined as follows of type `xs:anyType`

```
<xs:complexType name="prod">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:anyType" name="option" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"</xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

used in element mapping as follows

```
<xs:element name="mappings">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="prod" name="productionSystem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I have need to add following option type as one of the following

```
<xs:complexType name="Text">
        <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="id" />
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name" />
      </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Value">
      <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="id" />
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name" />
              <xs:element name="psValue" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

so basically one element option can be either of type Text or Value. 
I want to avoid `xsi:type` in the xml. hence defined as `xs:anyType`. However at runt time Jaxb Marshalling fails with error
"any of its super class is known to this context". How to ensure Text and Value are in Jaxb Context.

Can someone pls guide on same.

Thanks,
Anjana

Comment: can you add marshaling code.

Comment: I am using jaxb for marshaling, org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.

Comment: Any one face this issue with Jaxb2Marshller ?

Comment: If your question is how to add classes to `JAXBContext`  then , do something like this `JAXBContext.newInstance(     "com.package1:com.package2");` But I dont think that is the problem there.